# Is there an out of the box way to parse a list of 2-tuples with json4s?

Tags: scala, json4s

Given:

```
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

val json =
  """[
      {"myType":"type1","things":["1","2","3","4","5","6"]},
      {"myType":"type1","things":["1","2","3","4","5","6"]}
    ]"""

case class Stuff(myType: String, things: List[String])
parse(json).extract[List[Stuff]]
```

Scala produces this error at runtime:

```
An exception or error caused a run to abort: Temp and Temp$$anonfun$1$Stuff$3 disagree on InnerClasses attribute
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Temp and Temp$$anonfun$1$Stuff$3 disagree on InnerClasses attribute
```

Is there an out-of-the-box way to parse this with json4s, or is this a case for a custom serializer?

json4s version is 3.5.2

scala version is older due to a system limitation, 2.10.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an implicit `Formats` object in scope?

The `extract` method needs an implicit format parameter. Json4s provides default formatting for things like Lists.

The following code works for me

```
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods.parse

implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

val json =
  """[
      {"myType":"type1","things":["1","2","3","4","5","6"]},
      {"myType":"type1","things":["1","2","3","4","5","6"]}
  ]"""

case class Stuff(myType: String, things: List[String])
parse(json).extract[List[Stuff]]


res0: List[Stuff] = List(Stuff(type1,List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)), Stuff(type1,List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)))
```

json4s version 3.2.11

scala version 2.11

If you do have a implicit formatter in scope it may be a bug in json4s Reflector. Declaring your `Stuff` case class in a different place may fix the issue. See this github issue for details  https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues/84

Comment: My question didn't explicitly show that I was using the implicit. ;) It does, and I'l update the question. I'll also try moving the case class.

Comment: Moving the case class outside the main class fixed the problem. Interesting. Scala's cool, but sometimes...

Comment: Okay, then, so why does this occur? Is there a good reason for this or is it a bug somewhere?